# Digital trigger for analog output

Tags: python, triggers, nidaqmx

I want to trigger an analog output from a digital trigger on NI PCI 6713

http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371011c.pdf

According to the datasheet I can use PFI <0..9> and those pins are indeed shown in green in NI MAX with ao/StartTrigger

My code is the following:

```
    task = nidaqmx.Task()
    task.ao_channels.add_ao_voltage_chan("Dev12/ao0")
    task.triggers.start_trigger.cfg_dig_edge_start_trig("Dev12/PFI0")
    task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(rate=1)
    task.start()
    task.write([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0])
```

I recieve the following error:

```
DaqError: Source terminal to be routed could not be found on the device.

Make sure the terminal name is valid for the specified device. Refer to Measurement & Automation Explorer for valid terminal names.
Property: DAQmx_DigEdge_StartTrig_Src
Property: DAQmx_DigEdge_StartTrig_Edge
Source Device: Dev12
Source Terminal: Dev12/PFI0

Channel Name: Dev12/ao0

Task Name: _unnamedTask<1C>

Status Code: -89120
```

I use Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When specifying names for [channels](http://www.ni.com/documentation/en/ni-daqmx/latest/mxcncpts/physchannames/), the format is `device_name/channel_name`.
- For [physical terminals](http://www.ni.com/documentation/en/ni-daqmx/latest/mxcncpts/termnamesyntax/), the format is `/device_name/terminal`.

Note the leading slash for terminals:

```
task.ao_channels.add_ao_voltage_chan("Dev12/ao0")
task.triggers.start_trigger.cfg_dig_edge_start_trig("/Dev12/PFI0")
                                                     ^
                                                    Here
```

Comment: That is very confusing! thank you for the tip, I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere else!